# What facts can be derived from the MahaSankalpam sloka?

Tags: sankalpa

Generally we do a sankalpam before any pooja but during an annual cycle we recite the MahaSankalpam also. What is the meaning of the MahaSankalpam and what all scientific facts can be derived from them?

Comment: If you are talking about deshkallocharana it is the one to specify where are you performing pooja

Answer (score 4):

It gives current time and location of performer starting from lifetime of Brahma and place in Anda-Kataha.

Detailed answer in this [blog](http://proframanathan.blogspot.com/2014/05/sankalpam-and-its-meaning.html) :

**Dviteeya parardhe** - in the 2nd half of Brhama's life
**Svetavaraha kalpe** - in the kalpa of Sveta-Varaha
**Vaivaswatha manvantare** - in the reining period of current manu Vaivaswatha
**Ashta Vimsati tame** - in the 28th mahayuga of current manavantara
**Kaliyuge** - in kali yuga
**Prathame Padhe** - in first quarter of this yuga
**Jamboodveepe** - the jambu island
**Bharata Varshe**, **Bharata Kande** - in the land of Bharat
**Sakhabde Mero, Dakshine Parsve** - to South of Meru mountain
Asmin Varthamane Vyavaharike - in the current period now reigning
**Prabhavadi Shashti Samvatsaranam Madye** - among the cycle of 60 years starting from Prabhava
__ Nama **Samvatsare** - the name of year in 60 year Hindu calendar (current 2018-2019 is Vilambi)

__ **Ayane** - Half year : Uttara (mid-Jan to mid-July), or Dakshina (mid-July to mid-Jan)

__ **Ritou** - 6 seasons or Ritus - Vasantha, Greeshma, Varsha, Sharadh, Hemantha, Shishira

__ **Maase** - 12 months of Lunar/Solar calendar

__ **Pakshe** - Fortnight of waxing or waning moon : Shukla (day after Amavasya till and including Pournami) or 
Krishna (day after Pournami till and including Amavasya)

__ Subha **Thithou** - 15 days (tithi) between Pournami and Amavasya
(Prathama, Dvithiya, Trithiya,Chaturthi, Panchami, Shasti, Saptami, Ashtami, Navami, Dasami,Ekadasi, Dwadashi, Trayodasi, Chaturdasi, Pournami or Amavasya)

__ **Vasara** Yuktayam - week day : (Bhanu, Soma, Bhowma, Soumya, Guru, Brugu and Sthira)

__ **Nakshatra** Yuktayam - 27 stars or Nakshatra

__ **Yoga / Karana** - usually Shuba / Shuba

Read the blog I listed above for more explanation.

For details about [Vedic units of time](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time.html)

Comment: This is where I have problem. I am philosophically more Hindu but accepting such huge number of years look hard for me, that too cyclic.

Comment: The above answer is a very good explanation of the "Nitya Sankalpam", which is chanted on a daily basis for nitya karmas. However, the "Maha Sankalpam" actually describes the Brahmanda, as created by Brahma himself. This is chanted on special occasions, and is rarely heard these days.

Comment: The question is about details of Maha sankalpam. But your answer and the blog you have linked is talking about Sankalpa mantra chanted in nitya karmas. Please edit your answer or this might get deleted.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, this is the maha sankalpa chanted during upakarma etc.

Comment: @ram As far as I know, mahasankalpam is not chanted during uakarma. Only Sankalpam is chanted. For mahasankalpam, see [my question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16705/5212) asking source of Mahasankalpam. It contains more detail. The blog contains about sankalpam only.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, interesting.. hearing that for first time.

Comment: @SparkSunshine, that's because philosophically, you're not in advanced level of Hinduism yet.. if you're in the starting stages, yes it will look daunting. just like advanced calculus looks daunting to high-schooler even though he is mathematically inclined. it doesn't mean he should stop doing math. it also doesn't mean that the advanced math is wrong.